# Use two Facebook App ID in a single Android app

Tags: android, facebook, app-id

Need to switch between two Facebook App in a single android app. But the Facebook Andorid SDK accesses Facebook app ID from the Meta info defined in the Manifest and app ID defined in strings.xml file.

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/fbappid" />
```

Both of them cannot be updated in run-time.

Is there a way to include two Facebook APP ID in a single Android app ?

**USE CASE :**

Making an app for a Television channel. The app is designed for two different TV shows having respective Facebook apps. So when user switches between the two shows, have to initialize the Facebook SDK with the respective app ID.

Comment: What's your use-case for this? It might be possible to make it work but it'll probably cause many problems

Comment: why not just use one app for both shows? what if you want to show authorized friends? you will only be able to show them per app (app scoped and whatnot).

Comment: Correct. We can have a single app for both the shows. But there is already a big user base for both the apps. So the client wants to use two different apps. Would really appreciate if anyone could show a way to implement it.

Comment: @Igy Any clue for the solution ?

Comment: I think you're going to have a very hard time forcing this to work, I really wouldn't recommend it at all to be honest - it's going against the fundamental assumptions inherent in the design of the SDK

Comment: When you create a Session object, you can pass in an applicationId. You can also set an applicationId in Settings. Between both of these places, it should cover most of the use cases, but there may be some dialogs/legacy code that gets the appID from the manifest directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as per the comments and other research, Facebook Android SDK does not support multiple APP ID's.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to have multiple app ids, but you'd need to use FacebookSDK.setApplicationId("your_facebook_app_id") before the usage of Facebook SDK to switch between the apps.

I use it for applying for Facebook permissions as it needs to be a test app, I wouldn't recommend to use in production.